# can't get 16:9 ratio on kvm, only 16:10 or 4:3

Tags: windows, kvm, spice

I am running a Windows 7 KVM on CentOS 7. The Windows 7 guest resolutions are all 4:3 or 16:10

My monitor is 1920x1080, but KVM/Spice/Whatever is only offering me 1920x1200.

I don't know what part of the puzzle is causing this. I downloaded some drivers from here, http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/WindowsGuestDrivers but none of them seemed to be video drivers and when I try to update the adapter or display drivers Windows tells me I already have the best driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look here:
http://www.spice-space.org/download.html
There is a link to the windows QXL driver, as well as guest tools installer. However, I would recommend enabling RDP on the client and connecting with rdesktop, the performance will be much better.

Comment: On Linux Deepin client I installed package `xorgxrdp` and rebooted. Client now doesn't lag as much, but I still don't get `1366x768` resolution. I also installed `xserver-xorg-video-qxl` which doesn't give me additional resolutions... Any suggestion?